# Check if an CSS animation is completed with JQuery or JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Can I do this? An example -

CSS Code

```
div {
  animation-name: test
  animation-duration: 5s
}
@keyframes test{
  from {background-color: red;}
  to {background-color: blue;}    
}
```

Now, how do I make JQuery check if the animation is done? Plus I actually want to do this with a string that appears one word at a time, and then ask JQuery to see if it has completed, and if it has been shown fully then a 5 sec timer starts. Can I do this??

Thanks!

Comment: P.S. I am in Jquery 3.3.1

Comment: You would need to listen for the `animationend` or `webkitAnimationEnd` event in js. `$('.element').on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function() { })`

Comment: Ok, but if I use the webkit (I am on chrome) to add an event listener, how can I use that to trigger the timer? I am seeing this right now - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_animationend.asp. Thanks!

Comment: Oh. I see. Can I define the function outside? and then run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to for the `animationend` and `webkitAnimationEnd` events in javascript.

Like this:

```
$('div').on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function() { 
    alert('end');
});
```

```js
$('div').on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function() { 
 alert('end');
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  animation-name: test;
  animation-duration: 5s
}
@keyframes test {
  from {background-color: red;}
  to {background-color: blue;}    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```